# Query data using curl

Tags: php, curl

Why is it not working code, why - I do not understand. Code gets a response from curl and looking (must look) in this response word yes, if it is found - that displays the text - if not, then the other. The code:

```
    <?PHP 
// CURL
$ch = curl_init('http://dev.local/phpwhois-4.2.2/example.php?query=domain.ru&output=object');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0");
curl_setopt  ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$curl = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $curl;
curl_close($ch);

if(preg_match('~\s*yes\s*~u', $curl))
  echo 'Ok';
else
  echo 'Else text';
?>
```

Error strange, more precisely, its not quite there, but - if curl sends text yes, that does not work, then writes that else, and if it does not give a text - too else. If all the text that simply gives curl himself put in the variable it works.

That's what gives the script to curl `e (this answer in writing what else):

> regrinfo->Array disclaimer->Array 0->By submitting a query to RIPN's
>   Whois Service 1->you agree to abide by the following terms of use:
>   2->#3.2 (in Russian)
>   3-#3.2 (in English).
>   domain->Array name->hashcode.ru nserver->Array 
>   ns1.nameself.com->81.176.95.18  ns2.nameself.com->88.212.207.45
>   status->REGISTERED, DELEGATED, VERIFIED created->2010-11-05
>   expires->2014-11-05 source->TCI **registered->yes** regyinfo->Array
>   referrer-> registrar->RUCENTER-REG-RIPN
>   servers->Array 0->Array  server->ru.whois-servers.net 
>   args->hashcode.ru port->43 type->domain rawdata->Array 0->% By
>   submitting a query to RIPN's Whois Service 1->% you agree to abide by
>   the following terms of use: 2->%
>    (in Russian) 3->%
>    (in English). 4->
>   5->domain:   6->nserver:  . 7->nserver: 
>   . 8->state:  REGISTERED, DELEGATED, VERIFIED
>   9->person: Private Person 10->registrar: REGTIME-REG-RIPN
>   11->admin-contact:  12->created: 2010.11.05
>   13->paid-till: 2014.11.05 14->free-date: 2014.12.06 15->source: TCI
>   16-> 17->Last updated on 2014.07.27 12:31:31 MSK 18->

Comment: I suspect the unreadable output you get may actually have carriage returns. Don't let the browser render it as HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to set flag `return transfer`

```
<?PHP 
// CURL
$ch = curl_init('http://dev.local/phpwhois-4.2.2/example.php?query=domain.ru&output=object');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$curl = curl_exec($ch); 
echo $curl;
curl_close($ch);

if(preg_match('~\s*yes\s*~u', $curl))
  echo 'Ok';
else
  echo 'Else text';
?>
```

Take care also about timeouts in the future. Good luck.